# jQuery countdown function in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, countdown

I'm having a strange issue with IE8 and below where my countdown that's only supposed to fire once keeps fireing, something that doesn't happen in modern browsers. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks! The goal is to have a countdown start once an input is selected.

Code:

```
$("input").focus (function counter() {
  $("input").unbind('focus', counter);
  var count = 60;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $(".clock p").html(count);
    if (count == 0) {
      $(".while-ticking").fadeOut(1000);
      $(".countdown-finished").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {
        count--;
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$("input").focus(function() { counter(60) });

function counter(count) {
    $("input").unbind('focus');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".clock p").html(count);
        if (count == 0) {
            $(".while-ticking").fadeOut(1000);
            $(".countdown-finished").fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else {
            counter(count--);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Edit:** 
You need to create a loop for the counting down. So what i basicly do is starting with 60 wait a sec and recall the function again but then with 59.. etc. etc. when its 0 it doesnt call the function anymore so it stopt

**Edit:** 
I have test it the following and it worked :) counting down very well

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".............../jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("input").focus(function() { counter(60) });

    });

    function counter(count) {
        $("input").unbind('focus');
        $(".clock p").html(count);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (count == 0) {
                $(".while-ticking").fadeOut(1000);
                $(".countdown-finished").fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else {
                console.log(count--);
                counter(count--);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

</script>


<input type="text" />

<div class="clock">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Also, the unbind focus, counter is neccecary because otherwise the placeholdwer html attribute doesn't work. But thanks anyway.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that when more than one input field is selected it will fire again. Maybe I wasn't clear enough from the beginning.

Comment: It works fine in Firefox opera and chrome but still not in IE :/ Thanks a lot though. ANd when I put in counter function in unbind it refires in all browsers again. :(

Comment: The strange thing is that your entire code seems to be dependant on the console.log function, it doesn't work without it.