# Stop jQuery function from executing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, function, cross-browser

I'm having some code that sadly doesn't work in Internet Explorer and because it's not absolutely neccesary to have this code work in all browsers I'd like to stop it from executing in IE unless there is someway to fix it so it works in IE too (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979844/jquery-countdown-function-in-ie)  thread). How would this be (if it is) possible? Thanks

Comment: can't you `if (!$.browser.msie) doIt();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has functionality for seeing if a browser is any form of MSIE

```
if (!$.browser.msie) {
    // jquery function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional comment statements to do things in IE differently.

Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

You would want to test to see if the browser is not IE and then do the code.

Or you can use some jQuery browser detection which would allow you only to execute specific javascript code depending on the browser.

```
if (!$.browser.msie) {
    // jquery function
}
```

However I would recommend trying to get your javascript code to work in all browsers (maybe not IE6 ;) )

Comment: Yes, sadly I don't have so mcuh time and I can't seem to solve the problem, plus it's only a very minor detail I apreciate your help though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object exposes a "browser" property:

```
if (jQuery.browser !== "msie") {
  // do the thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ( !jQuery.browser.msie ) {
    //Your code
}
```